# Modify basic files used with gwbasic

Tags: printing, basic, lpt, gw-basic

I have a batch file which launches other .bas files with the help of gwbasic.
Here is the code of the batch file:

```
graphics
cd basic
gwbasic menut-hp/d
cd \
```

Then I have the possibility by typing 1 or 2 etc + ENTER to choose which program i want to run. The programs are located in the same directory as my batch file. The programs are xxx.BAS files.

The problem is:
I have a piece of software written in GWBASIC that currently is set up to just print locally to LPT1. 
When I disconnect the local printer, the software (gwbasic i guess) sends automatically the things to print to the network printer. 
The result is that a lot of A4 papers come out with only a few lines written.
On the local printer, the printer only printed when i exited the batch program.
On the network printer, it's like its non stop synchronizing, and not only when i exit the batch program.

I see 2 solutions:

- manage to put a tempo for the printing on the network printer (to refresh every 2 minutes for example)
- or try to add a line in the .BAS files, to save the text in a .txt of .pdf file, instead of printing it.. or print it in a pdf file.

I have almost no idea how gwbasic works, even after some researches.
Moreover, i haven't managed to view (and modify) the code of the .BAS files

Sorry for my bad english,

If anyone has any idea, it would help me a lot!

Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe later, but I enjoy scripting with BASIC and CONSOLE APP.

I recommend you run a command BAT before you BAS code to get default printer

```
wmic printer get name,default | find "TRUE" > Printer.txt
```

With this linen you get the similar response into Printer.txt

TRUE     Microsoft Print to PDF

After that, in your BAS code, read them and validate printer name or discard network printer before print.

Happy coding!